# In (Neo)Vim, how can I highlight the nearest pair of brackets which my cursor is inside of?

Tags: vim, highlight, neovim, parentheses, brackets

To be clear, I **don't want** to highlight matching brackets when I hover over a bracket.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
function foo(bar) {
```

Say my cursor is hovering over the `a` in `bar`. I want (Neo)Vim to highlight both parentheses surrounding `bar`.

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you want the venerable [showpairs](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/showpairs).

Comment: This does look like what I'm looking for, but the plugin isn't working for me. I placed `Plug 'vim-scripts/ShowPairs'` in my rc, installed it, played around with the highlighting, tried different terminal emulators, tried both Vim and Neovim, got nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that plugin is from a different era, with a funky "HelpExtractor" and all. Take a look at [the bottom of the script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim-scripts/ShowPairs/master/plugin/showpairs.vim) for some help. You may need to adjust a few things to make it work just like you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Neovim v0.4+ with [Tree-Sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter) support and the [nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) plugin installed, then you can use [theHamsta/nvim-treesitter-pairs](https://github.com/theHamsta/nvim-treesitter-pairs) *module* (see [the definition of a "*tree-sitter module*"](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter#available-modules) if you're unaware of it) to get highlighting for the current bracket pairs.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like with the plugin installed an configured.

[image]